Does the dominance of $f_{chemical}$ over $E$ explains the flow of electrons in a galvanic cell? How to explain flow in terms of less resistive path?
Consider this circuit, where the right side cell is a galvanic cell (discharging) and the right side cell is an electrolytic cell (charging). And suppose that $e'<e$.
Applying the Kirchoff's electric rule we get that $I=\frac{e-e'}{R}$, hence $I>0$.
That means:

that electrons flow from the $V^-$ terminal to the $V^+$ terminal, in the left electrolytic cell;
and that electrons flow from the $V^+$ terminal to the $V^-$ terminal, in the right galvanic cell.

My question is: what chemical / physical phenomena causes this flow of electrons within the cells?

Could it be that the approximation $\vec{f}_{chemical} + \vec{E}=0$ we make (i.e. no acceleration of the charge carriers inside the cells) is not quite accurate, and that instead, $\vec{f}_{chemical}$ dominates slightly more in the galvanic cell and that $\vec{E}$ dominates slightly more in the electrolytic cell, which in turn provokes the flow of the electrons?

According to this answer it could be related to the resistance of the path taken (i.e. the electron in the $V^-$ of the electrolytic cell prefers to go through the less resistive path of his own cell than through the more resistive path of the resistance plus the other cell). But what resistance are we talking about? Aren't the cells supposed to be resistiveless, in the sense that they are modeled as ideal generators?




Each electrode of an electrochemical cell (either galvanic either electrolytic) can be considered as chemically powered charge pump (like charge pumps in chips) that have the particular equilibrium potential.
If this potential is externally forced to change (passive circuit or external voltage), positive deviation causes the electrode pump is pumping electrons to the circuit while forming positive ion net charge in nearby electrolyte region. And vice versa for negative deviation.
These net charges cause potential gradient in the electrolyte and ion migration along this gradient.

You can imagine a copper rod, immersed in CuSO4 solution. It has some equilibrium reduction potential, at which the opposite reactions
$$\ce{Cu(s) -> Cu^2+(aq) + 2 e-(in metal)}$$
$$\ce{Cu^2+(aq) + 2 e-(in metal) ->  Cu(s)}$$
are ongoing at the same rate. If the potential of the electrode is externally raised by connecting it to a higher potential via passive or active circuit, then:
Reaction $\ce{Cu(s) -> Cu^2+(aq) + 2 e-(in metal)}$ goes faster, as less electric work is needed for leaving electrons in the metal and it lowers the energetic barrier for it.
Reaction $\ce{Cu^2+(aq) + 2 e-(in metal) ->  Cu(s)}$ goes slower, as more electric work is needed for leaving electrons in the metal and it raises  the energetic barrier for it.
And vice versa.
In both cases, the net chemical process acts against the external disturbance. The momentary potential is then result of ratio of internal resistances $\dfrac{\text{d}E}{\text{d}I}$  of external circult and the electrode.
$$E_\text{electrode} = \frac{E_\text{0, electrode} \cdot R_\text{circuit} + E_\text{0, circuit} \cdot R_\text{electrode}}{R_\text{circuit} + R_\text{electrode}}$$
If the potential is raised above the equilibrium, the electrode oxidizes the electrolyte and pumps electrons to the metal to lower it back.
If the potential is lowered below equilibrium, the electrode reduces the electrolyte by "sucking" electrons from the metal, raising the potential back.
Note that the internal resistance of the electrochemical electrode is a comlicated functions of potential, time and electrode conditions.

So stationary state approximation (i.e. $\vec{f}_{chemical} + \vec{E}=\vec{0}$) is transgressed so that electrons can flow ? Or it has nothing to do and the electrons have a constant velocity inside the cells ?

There are no free electrons inside the cells, aside of electrons in conductive bands of metallic conductors.

"can be considered as a pump that have the particular equilibrium potential" do you mean that reduction potential $E_{red}$ is the same for the two electrodes (when there is no external circuit) ?

Only if they are identical, including the electrolyte.

You can find tons of studying materials by browsing  https://chem.libretexts.org, or by using targetted search site:chem.libretexts.org

"the opposite reactions are ongoing at the same rate". Does that mean that $\Delta G = 0$ when the circuit is open? I thought that $ΔG=−n\mathfrak F E_{cell}$ independently of whether the circuit is open or closed. Is there any formula that backs the fact that $\Delta G = 0$ when the circuit is open?

The electrodes are in local equilibrium,  but the whole cell is not. If it were, the cell would have the open voltage 0 V.

I think that I have a bit overcomplicated the problem. In fact, studying the sign difference between the left EMF and the right EMF, boils down to studying the sign (i.e. whether it's positive or negative) of a simple cell.
Once this is done, and bearing in mind that positive EMF means spontaneous reaction (and negative EMF non-spontaneous reaction), we can easily see that the flow of ionic charges inside the cell is due to the difference of reduction potential of the two red/ox couples, corrected by the concentrations of the species according to the Nernst equation.

Motion of ionic charge carriers is caused by local ion charge disbalances, caused by electrode charge activities during nonzero current. This disbalance causes voltage gradient across the electrolyte, making ions to move
